# Change the default Post/Page edit title in Admin

Tags: wp-admin

When editing a lot of pages at once, it would be helpful to change the default "Edit page < sitename - Wordpress" to something more clear, like the page/post title.

I found a few code snippets, like the one below, that doesn't work, I just get an empty page title.

Using WordPress 5.8.2 and have the code infunctions.php.

```
add_filter('admin_title', 'better_admin_title', 10, 2);

function better_admin_title($admin_title, $title)
{
    global $post, $title, $action, $current_screen;
    if (is_admin() and $action == 'edit' and in_array($current_screen->id, ['post', 'page'])) {
        return $title . ' ‹ ' . $post->post_title . ' — ' . get_bloginfo('name');
    }

    return $admin_title;
}
```

Comment: code seems to be fine. I tested it. Try changing priority and see if that helps

Comment: I tried, but the title is empty. What priority changes do you recommend?

Comment: try setting it to 9999

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.